# How to fill out wifi settings file for raspberry pi

Tags: wifi, settings, raspbian

I need to fill out a settings file for my raspberry pi, which looks like this:

```
[connection]
id=hassos-network
uuid=e0638ca6-cd7a-4e82-9812-2984b9f01a4w
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
mode=infrastructure
ssid=mywifinetworkname

[802-11-wireless-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=mywifipassword

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=auto
```

What I have done so far:

- generate a new UUID
- fill out my ssid / Wi-Fi name
- fill out my Wi-Fi password

For the rest - how do I fill them out and how do I find out what values are right for my network?

The only thing I know, is that I log in via WPA/WPA2 Personal, but how do I describe that? wpa2-psk ? wpa-wpa2 ? I also have both 5g and 2.4ghz with the names 802.11a/n/ac mixed and 802.11b/g/n mixed.

I am using a mac.

Comment: What application on the RasPI uses this settings file? It's neither typical for **wpa_supplicant** nor for **hostapd**.

Comment: Try [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: It's for Hass.io